# Field in active directory to store transliterated/original person name?

Tags: active-directory, transliteration

I wonder if I have a user that has name in non latin character set (eg. Юрий Гагарин).

What is recommendation to store name - as transliterated representation (Jurij Gagarin)?

And is there any field that can store original name?

I've checked list of user attributes (http://www.kouti.com/tables/userattributes.htm) but I haven't found anything that can fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't find an attribute that was created for exactly that purpose, but there are several single-value string attributes that are often unused. You can just use one of those, as long as no one else in your organization is not using it for something else.

One attribute that is usually unused, but actually kind of makes sense to use for this is [`adminDisplayName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/adschema/a-admindisplayname).

Otherwise, you could just create your own attribute. You *can* [add attributes to your schema](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/51121.active-directory-how-to-add-custom-attribute-to-schema.aspx), but I think that's a bit overkill just for a plain-text attribute.